# Unity 5 Command not being sent

Tags: c#, networking, unity, unity-networking

I have a client server build in Unity 5. I want to send a command from the client to the server with a GUI button click, this is for testing purposes. So on my client all I want is to click a button and then have the server display a message on its console window. Reading through http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetActions.html this seems to require a player object. With the demo I am trying to create there is no player. So I created an empty game object and called it player and assigned it a player script:

```
public class Player : NetworkBehaviour {

void Update () 
{   //receive message from camera follow script to run command from client to server
    if (isServer)
        return;

    if (GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<CameraFollow>().sendCommand) 
    {
        CmdTurnOnNetworkTransformOnServer ();
    }
}

[Command]
void CmdTurnOnNetworkTransformOnServer()
{
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log ("Received");
}
}
```

This script checks if a boolean is true on another script (the script that contains the GUI button that when clicked sets the bool to true). if it is true then I would like the server to display "Received" on the console in the editor. However I get the error "Trying to send command for non-local player." From what I can see I am following the above link properly to just display a simple message. I realise there is another route with http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetMessages.html however I would like to see if I can get a command working instead.

Full Error: Trying to send command for non-local player.
UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkBehaviour:SendCommandInternal(NetworkWriter, Int32, String)
Player:CallCmdTurnOnNetworkTransformOnServer()
Player:Update() (at Assets/Player.cs:37)

How come I am getting this error?

This error appears in the client console window

Comment: Maybe it is being called on a non-local player?

Comment: @andeart could you expand on this? What am I missing or not doing? I don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading through http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetActions.html a player object is required. This player object should be a prefab and fill the space beside player prefab under spawn info within the network manager script in the editor. I created an invisible player object, so it may aswell not be there, but for the purposes of sending a command it should be. This avoids the error of sending a command for a non-local player.